# snowflake connector timeout due to OSCP certificate checks

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We need to find out why we get a timeout when we try to connect to snowflake via lambda function using the snowflake connector for python. I found a not really secure way to make it works  using a specific parameter (insecure_mode) inside the connector as follow:

```py
connection = snowflake.connector.connect(user=sf_user,password=sf_password,account=sf_account,warehouse=sf_warehouse,database=sf_database,schema=sf_schema,insecure_mode=True)
```

We tried using insecure_mode to False and True

This piece of code doesn't work and fails with timeout error due probably to oscp checks.

```py
connection = snowflake.connector.connect(user=sf_user,password=sf_password,account=sf_account,warehouse=sf_warehouse,database=sf_database,schema=sf_schema)
```

This piece of code works but unsecure I guess :

```py
connection = snowflake.connector.connect(user=sf_user,password=sf_password,account=sf_account,warehouse=sf_warehouse,database=sf_database,schema=sf_schema,insecure_mode=True)
```

I expect the result to be working without timeout when using insecure_mode to false