# Intermittent Problem connecting to Snowflake

Tags: sqlalchemy, azure-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have an Azure Function App running Python that conects to Snowflake database like below:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import Connection

        engine = create_engine(conn_str)
        connection = engine.connect().execution_options(autocommit=autocommit)
```

package used below:

```
snowflake-connector-python==2.7.9
numpy==1.23.0 
pandas==1.3.5
snowflake-connector-python[pandas]==2.7.9
sqlalchemy==1.4.41
snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.5.0
```

But the connection is frozen sometimes after OCSP like below:

> 2023-10-03 17:24:40.897 Snowflake Connector for Python Version: 2.7.9,
> Python Version: 3.9.18, Platform:
> Linux-5.15.116.1-1.cm2-x86_64-with-glibc2.31 Information 2023-10-03

> 17:24:40.904 This connection is in OCSP Fail Open Mode. TLS
> Certificates would be checked for validity and revocation status. Any
> other Certificate Revocation related exceptions or OCSP Responder
> failures would be disregarded in favor of connectivity. Information

> 2023-10-03 17:24:40.769 Timeout value of 00:30:00 exceeded by function
> 'Functions.test_function' (Id: 'xxx-xx-xx-xx-xx'). Initiating
> cancellation. Error

Questions:

1 Why was the db connection frozen?

2 Is it possible to look up database logs for each request received from Snowflake? So I can see when the request was received by Snowflake.

Comment: Does the function app timeout cover the time limit for the connection to be successful? Or the limits on the Azure function app could be causing this.

Comment: So, you're not able at all to establish a connection with Snowflake? 30 min for establishing a connection would be way too much.

Comment: It is sometimes working, sometimes not as mentioned in the title and content.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're facing is the known error mentioned in the [**Snowflake Document**](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ocsp#fail-open).  Make sure you are using the latest Python connector mentioned in this Document for your snowflake connection. Refer this [**SO thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58449793/snowflake-connector-timeout-due-to-oscp-certificate-checks) by Rohan Gupta

> **SnowSQL v1.1.79** **or later**, **Python Connector v1.8.0 or later**, **SQL Alchemy Upgrade Python Connector to v1.8.0 or later**

In your **requirements.txt** do not specify any version for your pip packages, Directly add them to use the latest version:-

My **requirement.txt**:-

```
azure-functions
snowflake-connector-python
sqlalchemy
snowflake-sqlalchemy
```

**My init.py:-**

```py
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    # Snowflake connection details
    snowflake_account = 'xxxxw80422'
    snowflake_user = 'xxxxLERN1'
    snowflake_password = 'xxxxxdYS'
    snowflake_database = 'DEMO'
    snowflake_schema = 'Public'
    snowflake_warehouse = 'COMPUTE_WH'
    snowflake_role = 'ACCOUNTADMIN'
    
    # Construct Snowflake connection string
    conn_str = (
        f'snowflake://{snowflake_user}:{snowflake_password}@'
        f'{snowflake_account}/{snowflake_database}/{snowflake_schema}'
        f'?warehouse={snowflake_warehouse}&role={snowflake_role}'
    )

    try:
        # Create SQLAlchemy engine and connect
        engine = create_engine(conn_str)
        connection = engine.connect()

        # Perform database operations here
        # For example, execute a query
        result = connection.execute("SELECT * FROM DEMO1")

        # Process the result or perform other operations
        
        return func.HttpResponse("Successfully connected to Snowflake!", status_code=200)
    
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error connecting to Snowflake: {str(e)}")
        return func.HttpResponse("Failed to connect to Snowflake", status_code=500)
```

**Local Output:-**

[image]

**Function Output:-**

*I have deployed this Function in a Dedicated Plan.*

[image]

[image]

***You can debug the Connection Errors by visiting > Diagnose and Solve Problems > Function Execution Performance:-***

[image]

Comment: the images are not visible. this link as no answer now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58449793/snowflake-connector-timeout-due-to-oscp-certificate-checks. removing the version number could be risky.